# N box, each has k seeds, but total only m "good" seeds. What is probability that there is at least 1 box which has at least t "good" seed

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

There are $n$ boxes, each contains $k$ seeds.
Knowing in those $n\times k$ seeds, there are $m$ seeds which are "good" seeds.
Calculate the probability of:

- There is at least **one** box which has at least $t$ "good" seeds in it.
- There are at least **two** boxes which each has at least $t$ "good" seeds in it.
- There are at least $i$ boxes which each has at least $t$ "good" seeds in it.

Attempt:

So far it is easy with $t = 2$ and $i = 1$. But with higher $t$ and $i$, I cannot find an answer. This is my first time on Math Stack Exchange, so please excuse me for any informality.

Comment: Total there are m seeds

Comment: Specifically, can we assume that each of the $m$ good seeds is equally likely *a priori* to be in any of the $n$ boxes?  And that they are placed independently of each other?

Comment: It might help if you give your answer for $t = 2$ and $i = 1$, and roughly how you obtained it.  Please provide this in your original question, not in a response to this comment.

Comment: First find without a constraint of m good seeds. At least t means, a box can even have k good seeds. That case will change how many rest boxes can really have t good seeds or more.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume that the distribution of seeds between boxes is independent of the quality to be "good" or "bad".

Then the probability of the event that the boxes $1,2\dots n$  contain $m_1, m_2,\dots,m_n$ good seeds, respectively, is:
$$
\frac{\frac{m!}{m_1!m_2!\cdots m_n!}\cdot\frac{(nk-m)!}{(k-m_1)!(k-m_1)!\cdots(k-m_n)!}}{\frac{(nk)!}{k!^n}}=\frac{\prod_{i=1}^n\binom k{m_i}}{\binom{nk}m}.
$$

The probability that *exactly* $j$ boxes contain at least $t$ good seeds is then:
$$
p(t,j)=\binom{nk}m^{-1} [x^m]\left[\binom nj\left(\sum_{s=0}^{t-1}\binom ksx^s\right)^{n-j} \left(\sum_{s=t}^{n}\binom ksx^s\right)^{j}\right],
$$
where $[x^m]$ is the coefficient extractor giving the coefficient at $x^m$ in the series expansion of the following expression.

Finally, the probability that *at least* $i$ boxes contain at least $t$ good seeds reads:
$$
\sum_{j=i}^n p(t,j).
$$